# How do I paste format with google sheets script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, scripting

I'm copying and pasting data from one tab to another within my sheet using below code. The problem is several of the columns are w/l records showing as "9-2" (for ex) and the data is being pasted as values. The w/l records are then incorrectly recalibrated in the 'short date' format.

```
function copyData() { 

  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=ss.getSheetByName('Standings - live');
  var rg=sh.getRange("A40:P69");
  var vA=rg.getValues();
  var tsh=ss.getSheetByName('Daily Result');
  var trg=tsh.getRange(tsh.getLastRow()+1,1,30,16);
  trg.setValues(vA);
}
```

The thing is, I need the paste values to clear the logic/syntax out of my cells on the original paste. How do I then add a second step to 'paste format' *over* the same range to reset the w/l records to the proper format?

Comment: In order to correctly understand about your situation, can you provide the sample Spreadsheet for replicating your issue, and also, can you include the output you expect to it? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Are you familiar with [copyTo(destination, options)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#copytodestination,-options) which enables a script to copy values and/or formats. There are also other alternatives - the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#top_of_page) is a good place to start

Comment: Thanks @tedinoz for replying. I didn't use your solution - rather copied a cell holding a formatted record, then pasted that format in the destination columns on my destination tab.

Now, even though I'm pasting values, they are transferred into the preferred format because the cell holds that format ahead of time.

Answer (score 4):

```
function testTemplate()
{
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var template=ss.getSheetByName("Test Sheet")
  var destSheet=ss.getSheetByName("Sheet1")
  var lr=destSheet.getLastRow()
  var lc=destSheet.getLastColumn()
  template.getRange(9,2,3,6).copyTo(destSheet.getRange(2,1,lr,lc), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_FORMAT, false)
}
```

Comment: Can you make a comment explaing what the code does?

Answer (score 0):

I answered with my comment above. For pasting the format, copy the cell while it's in the preferred format, then paste format in the destination cells.

Paste format (for mac): option + command + v

By placing the preferred format in the destination cells ahead of time, I avoided having to script-in formatting.

Comment: Hi. I'm really pleased that this worked out and that you want to answer your own question. What you need to do is show the code with the changes that you've made. That will be much value to others who read your answer at a later date.